# Models/IdentityModel.cs missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .NET and currently learning ASP.NET Core MVC by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db).

My development environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- .Net Core 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
- Visual Studio Code 1.7.2
- generator-aspnet 0.2.5 (creates project scaffolding)

So, I created a new project using `yo aspnet` and selected `Web Application`, which includes Individual User Accounts-based authentication. In the tutorial, I'm now at the "Create your model" section and feeling confused on how to proceed.

Specifically, the model the tutorial asks you to create looks like this:

**Models/Model.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models
{
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, on that page, there's a warning:

> If you use Individual User Accounts instead of None for Authentication
>   then an Entity Framework model will be added to your project in
>   Models\IdentityModel.cs. Using the techniques you will learn in this
>   walkthrough, you can choose to add a second model, or extend this
>   existing model to contain your entity classes.

My confusion started when I could not find the file they reference, Models/IdentityModel.cs. I do see **Models/ApplicationUser.cs**, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

... and **Data/ApplicationDBContext.cs**, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models;
namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

The warning message above has me confused on how to proceed. Since Models/IdentityModel.cs does not exist, do I place the contents of Model.cs into Models/ApplicationUser.cs or Data/ApplicationDBContext.cs or do I leave everything as is?

Answer (score 2):

> I could not find the file they reference, Models/IdentityModel.cs.

`generator-aspnet` is using [different version of templates](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/tree/master/templates/projects/web)  than [Visual C# Web Template shipped with Visual Studio 2015](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/tree/VS2015.RTM).

File [`Models/IdentityModel.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/VS2015.RTM/src/Rules/StarterWeb/IndividualAuth/Models/IdentityModels.cs) should contain classes `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationDbContext`. They are the same as in the version used by `generator-aspnet`.

> do I place the contents of Model.cs into Models/ApplicationUser.cs or
>   Data/ApplicationDBContext.cs or do I leave everything as is

You can leave it as it is - it does not matter where are these files located.

Answer (score 0):

You probably selected "No Authentication" and that is why you do not have the "Models/IdentityModel.cs" file

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Text only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do. Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote

Answer (score -1):

The warning is for when you selected other than **No Authentication** for authentication method.

In case you selected **Individual User Account**, a new Entity Framwork model will be create for the use database.

You probably selected "No Authentication" and that is why you do not have the "`Models/IdentityModel.cs`" file

Comment: Curious about the downvote, that's a correct statement.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted this but probably the reason for downvote was that statement is not correct (or at least not always correct). When creating an ASP.NET Core MVC app, I don't get anything close to IdentityModel.cs (or IdentityModels.cs) in the project. Tried with .NET Core 1.0, .NET Core 2.0, and .NET Core 2.2, with both Individual Accounts and No Authentication.